# Strange linker error with static array of int

Tags: c++, c++11

I was trying to compile the following code with Clang 3.0.
It fails to link, am I doing something wrong here or this is a compiler bug?

The error follows

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "__ZN9int_arrayIJLi0ELi1ELi2ELi3ELi4ELi5ELi6ELi7ELi8EEE4listE",
>   referenced from:
>         __ZN9int_arrayIJLi0ELi1ELi2ELi3ELi4ELi5ELi6ELi7ELi8EEE5printEv
>   in cc-JDTbNl.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

The code follows

```
#include <iostream>

static const int a[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

template<int... Numbers> struct int_array;

template<int... Numbers>
struct int_array {
  int x;
  const static int list[] = {Numbers...};
  static void print() {
    for (const int x : list) {
        std::cout << x <<std::endl;
    }
  }
  static void print2() {
    for (const int x : a) {
        std::cout << x <<std::endl;
    }
  }
};

typedef int_array<0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8> array_of_ints;

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  array_of_ints::print();
  array_of_ints::print2();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong for two reasons

- You cannot initialize a static data member in-class if it is not of integer or enumeration type and not `constexpr`
- You miss a definition for `int_array<yournumbers>::list`. As you are odr-using that member, you need to define it.

It's not a clang bug. Once clang gets `constexpr` support and when you then add a definition of out class (which then cannot have an initializer), as you already provided one in-class) and replace `const` by `constexpr` the code should then work fine.

---

For the general public, [here is the PR that @James sent to Clang](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=10714).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at all an expert on c++0x, and hope somebody more knowledgeable would come here... but does C++0x allow in-class initialization of static members? If so, clang just doesn't implement it yet. If not, you can't. 
[The (almost) standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf), 9.4.2 item 3, says any const literal type can be initiazlied; and 3.9 item 10 says an array of int is a literal. So, I guess this is a bug of clang 3.0, but there may be further rules in the case of variadic templates...

Anyway, changing your code as follows worked for me:

```
template<int... Numbers>
struct int_array {
  int x;
  const static int list[];
  static void print() ;
};

template<int... Numbers>
const int int_array<Numbers...>::list[]={Numbers...};

template<int... Numbers>
void int_array<Numbers...>::print(){
    for (const int x : list) {
        std::cout << x <<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think in-class initialization is only allowed for static const *integral* members.

Comment: Thank you for you response on this I will submit this as possible bug to the clang guys

Comment: @Kerek That was the situation in C++03, I think. In C++11, it's OK to have in-class initialization for any literal const static members.